# Want to take a map to a slice structure

Tags: go

I have a map with a key and a value structure that i want to put into a simple slice.

The struct I want to store the values as ,

```
type Attribute struct {
    AttId      container.AttrID
    AttMess []json.RawMessage
}
```

The current loop I have is something like this which takes the keys from the existing map,

```
    keys := make([]container.AttrID, 0, len(AttId))
    for k := range AttId {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }

    for _, k := range keys {
        fmt.Println(k, AttId[k])
    }
```

How would I construct a slice that holds the keys and values inside attributes with the struct above? I'm a bit lost if you can actually make this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply range over the map and construct instances of the struct. Assuming the map values are `[]json.RawMessage` types:

```
attrs:=make([]Attribute,0,len(attributes))
for k,v:=range attributes {
   attrs=append(attrs,Attribute{AttributesId:k, AttributesMessage:v})
}
```

Comment: Awesome - only issue is it returns this error,

cannot use v (variable of type json.RawMessage) as []json.RawMessage value in struct literalcompilerIncompatibleAssign

Comment: in that case, what you need to declare in the `Attribute` is a `json.RawMessage`, not `[]json.RawMessage`

Comment: Thanks. Other issue, now running it, it says the attrs is declared but not used, even though it is being appended and used to return a value at the end of the function. Confused why it would say it isn't being used?

Comment: See the fixed answer